# React Native expo unstable press delay not working fully

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to make a reaction time screen where users would press the screen so it goes red and then after a random amount of time it will turn green where they will have to release it. However, currently the pressIn is called immediately after I pressOut or after the delay. This means users cab tap through the UI.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Platform,TouchableOpacity ,Pressable ,ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions ,useWindowDimensions,ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import {MaterialCommunityIcons, Ionicons, Entypo, AppIcon} from "@expo/vector-icons";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  SafeAreaProvider,
  SafeAreaInsetsContext,
  useSafeAreaInsets,
  initialWindowMetrics,
} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import * as SystemUI from 'expo-system-ui'
//import {useEffect} from 'react';


import BottomNavigationBar from './BottomNavigationBar';'./BottomNavigationBar'
import styles from './Styles'
import { entireScreenHeight,entireScreenWidth,os } from '../App';
import { setBackgroundColorAsync } from 'expo-navigation-bar';

let startTime = 0 
let finishTime = 0



const colours = ['cyan', 'red', 'lime'] 
let c = 0



export default function ReactionScreen({navigation}) {
   
    const [count,setCount] = React.useState(c);
    const max = 5000 
    const min = 500

    function nothing () {}

    function start () {
        console.log('---',c)
        setCount(change)
        setTimeout(starting,1000)
        //await sleep(Math.random() * (max-min) + min)
    }
    function starting () {
        setCount(change)
        startTime = performance.now()
        console.log(startTime)
    }
    function stop () {
        finishTime = performance.now()      
        console.log(startTime,finishTime)
        speed = Math.round(finishTime-startTime)
        console.log(speed+'ms')

        
        setCount(0)
        c = 0  
    }

   function change () {
        if ( c === 2){
            c = -1 
        }
        c+=1 
        return c
    }
    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider style = {{backgroundColor: colours[count]}}>
            <Pressable onPressIn = {start}
            unstable_pressDelay={1000}
            onPressOut={stop} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'transparent',}} android_ripple={{ color: 'blue', borderless: false, foreground: true }} >
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
      name="lightning-bolt"
      size={0.25*entireScreenWidth}
      color="#7F00FF"
      style={[styles.buttonIcon,{textAlign: 'center', bottom: '-30%'}]}
       />
       <Text style={[styles.buttonLabel(0.1),{textAlign: 'center', bottom: '-60%'}]}>Press to Start</Text>
      </Pressable>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
}

//<SafeAreaView style = {[styles.navigationContainer,{}]}>
//<BottomNavigationBar/>
//</SafeAreaView>
```

I tried changing the delay but it still didn't prevent me from tapping instantly for the same result as pressing.